# php extending mysqli and preparing statements

Tags: php, mysqli

So I copied a class from code on another stackoverflow post:

```
class db extends mysqli{
  protected static $instance;
  protected static $options = array();

  private function __construct() { $o = self::$options;
    // turn of error reporting
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);

    // connect to database
    @parent::__construct(isset($o['host'])   ? $o['host']   : 'localhost',
      isset($o['user'])   ? $o['user']   : 'root',
      isset($o['pass'])   ? $o['pass']   : 'password',
      isset($o['dbname']) ? $o['dbname'] : 'database',
      isset($o['port'])   ? $o['port']   : 3306,
      isset($o['sock'])   ? $o['sock']   : false );
    if( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
      throw new exception(mysqli_connect_error(), mysqli_connect_errno());
    }
  } 

  public static function getInstance(){
    if(!self::$instance ){
      self::$instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }

  /** OTHER METHOD NOT SHOWN FOR CLARITY **/
}
```

This class works just fine, and I am able to prepare statements as follows:

```
$sql = db::getInstance();
$sql->query($dropExampleTable);
$sql->query($ExampleTable);

$title = 'this is an example';

if($stmt = $sql->prepare($exampleQuery)){
  $stmt->bind_param("s",$title);   

  if(!$stmt->execute()){
    echo "example: successful <br />";
  }
}else{
  echo "example: failed <br />";
}
```

This will successfully add an item into the database. Now this is where my question begins: Why is it that if I add the following method to my *db* class I am not able to create and successfully execute a statement?

```
  public function func(){    

    if($stmt = self::$instance->prepare($exampleQuery)){    
      $name = 'func';   
      $stmt->bind_param("s",$name);    
      if(!$stmt->execute()){   
        echo "example: successful <br />";  
      }
    }else{  
      echo "example: failed <br />";
    }                                                  
  }
```

Even if I pass the sql object created with *getInstance()* as a reference, I am still unable to successfully prepare a statement:

```
  public function func2(&$sql){    

    if($stmt = $sql->prepare($exampleQuery)){    
      $name = 'func2';   
      $stmt->bind_param("s",$name);    
      if(!$stmt->execute()){   
        echo "example: successful <br />";  
      }
    }else{  
      echo "example: failed <br />";
    }                                                  
  }
```

BUT I am able to create a statement as I did at the top of the post, and pass it as a reference and execute that statement in a method I create inside the *db* class:

```
  public function func3(&$stmt){    

    $name = 'func3';   
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$name);    
    if(!$stmt->execute()){   
      echo "example: successful <br />";  
    }
  }
```

But I don't want to have to pass a prepared statement to my class; seems to defeat the purpose of it. My ultimate goal is to be able to pass an array of items that need to be added to the database to my *db* instance and prepare the statement inside a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of a singleton object is to have only one instance of an object, that's why the constructor method is private. Which means that you cannot call any non-static methods, in your case you `func` function is actually not a static one - that needs to be changed. Then, in that method, it seems that you have place the `else` statement on the first `if`, if you really want to see if statement was executed correctly, you should move it to the other `if`. Here is a slightly updated version of your method, it works fine:

```
public static function func($exampleQuery)
{
    if ($stmt = self::$instance->prepare($exampleQuery)) {    
        $name = 'some name'; // search criteria
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {   
            echo "example: successful <br />";  
        } else {
            echo "example: failed <br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
$db = db::getInstance();
$db->func('SELECT `id` FROM `table` WHERE `name` = ?');
// prints out 'example: successful '
```

Comment: This updated version worked. Thank you so much. I should do my research on "singleton objects."